# Simple reference for $\infty$ categorical mate correspondence

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

I am looking for a reference for the the following statement that is related to the mate correspondence for natural transformations.

Let $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ be $\infty$-categories, and let $F: \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ be left adjoint to $G$. Let $X: \mathcal C \to \mathcal D'$ and $Y:\mathcal D \to \mathcal D'$ be functors.  Then there is a homotopy equivalence $${\rm Nat}(XG, Y) \simeq {\rm Nat}(X, YF),$$ where ${\rm Nat}(A,B)$ denotes the mapping space in the functor $\infty$-category.

There is a paper proving a general $\infty$-categorical mate correspondence by  Haugseng, Hebestreit, Linskens, Nuiten.  However the statement I need is much simpler, and I believe it can be proved directly following the same argument as the $1$-categorical case (interpreted in a $2$-category enriched in the homotopy category of spaces).  Does anyone happen to know a source where this equivalence is stated,  or where the $h {\mathcal K}an$ enriched $2$-category of $\infty$-categories is discussed?

Comment: I don't know a reference but certainly this follows easily from the unit/counit perspective on adjunctions - namely the unit/counit for $F\dashv G$ provide a unit/counit for $G^*\dashv F^*$ (where $H^*$ means "precomposition by $H$")

Comment: Have you looked in Riehl and Verity's book?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Thanks! This argument is a bit more concise than what I had in mind (i.e. writing out the inverse equivalences using the unit/co-unit transformations).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is Proposition 5.2.2.8 in Higher Topos Theory. Lurie introduces the notion of a "unit transformation", which means a homotopy equivalence just like the one you want.